# How to avoid multiple copies of a list when mapping a pure function to it?

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

Given this code:

```
mylist = Tuples[{a, e}, 2];
Insert[mylist, 1, {#, 3}] & /@ Range[2]
```

The output is this:

> {{{a, a, 1}, {a, e}, {e, a}, {e, e}}, {{a, a}, {a, e, 1}, {e, a}, {e, 
>   e}}}

But the desired output is this:

> {{a, a, 1}, {a, e,1}, {e, a}, {e, e}}

Apparently `mylist` is multiplied along the way. How to avoid this?

Comment: Try `Insert[mylist, 1, {{1, 3}, {2, 3}}]` to get your output, which you could also write as `Insert[mylist, 1, {#, 3} & /@ Range[2]]` if you want to use `Range`.

Comment: @MarcoB I am trying to understand the principle, such that I can also apply it in more complicated situations with more data. Then your solution is not efficient...

Comment: Your command generates a list of lists, each one with a single substitution. You want a single list, with two substitutions instead. There is a fundamental disconnect there, I'm afraid. It might be helpful to look at the output of `Inactive[Insert][mylist, 1, {#, 3}] & /@ Range[2]`, i.e. to see the effect of mapping before the insertion happens.

Comment: Related: [(30647)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30647/121), [(145999)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145999/121)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(36950)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36950/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mylist = Tuples[{a, e}, 2];
```

I think `MapAt` would be a good candidate here

```
MapAt[Append[#, 1] &, mylist, List /@ Range[2]]
```

> {{a, a, 1}, {a, e, 1}, {e, a}, {e, e}}

If you want `Insert`:

```
Fold[Insert[#1, 1, {#2, -1}] &, mylist, Range@2];
```

Or

```
Insert[mylist, 1, Thread[{Range@2, 3}]]
```

> {{a, a, 1}, {a, e, 1}, {e, a}, {e, e}}

The problem with succesive insertions (and so with your idea) is that already after the first insertion the original positions have changed.